# What MIME type are you meant to use for JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, http

In the html we always use <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="???"></script> (the ECMA stuff confuses some browsers) but on the HTTP side what are you meant to use as the Content-Type?

By instinct this would also be text/javascript, but Apache uses application/javascript and Amazon uses application/x-javascript.

Some firewall admins block any MIME types matching application/*; but which MIME type are you meant to use from a webmaster perspective? What is the "right" thing to do.

Comment: You're missing a closing ".

Comment: @Hello71 Good observation no wonder W3 Validation always complains at my mark-up ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct `Content-Type` is `application/javascript`

See: [What is the Javascript MIME Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: application/javascript it is - with text/javascript in the mark-up *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/mime-types/) has a list of what's accepted by which browser, for example:

> `text/javascript`
>   Opera 7.54+
>   IE 5+
>   Firefox 1.0.7+
>   Safari 2.0.3+
>   iCab 3 Beta 394
>   Camino 2006021400